# Targeting Multiple Scenes

Tags: iphone, if-statement, cocos2d-iphone

I have a scene that is displayed before a level, where the images are loaded. During this I show text about the game. I would like the text to appeal to what Level it is. How can I do something like "if Level is 5-9", and then the rest of the code.

Basically my way of explaining is:

```
       if (currentLevel.Level 5-9) { 
//do stuff 
    }
```

By Level5-9 I mean Levels 5, 6, 7, 8, 9. Tell me if you need more explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (currentLevel >=5 && currentLevel <= 9) { 
    // do stuff 
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! Will accept answer (it's telling me wait 5 minutes).

Comment: Hey btw, how can I do the same thing, but with randomly selected levels? I want to make some texts appear at random Levels